# Tutorial Building a ROS Package: "Rosdep experienced an internal error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'"

Tags: pcl, rosdep, tutorial, turtlesim, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm new to to ROS and Linux. I'm running ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04.

While going through the "BuildingPackages" tutorial I experienced a problem. After typing

```
rosdep install turtlesim
```

I get the error message:

> ERROR: Rosdep experienced an internal
> error: 'NoneType' object has no
> attribute 'copy' Please go to the
> rosdep page [1] and file a bug report
> with the stack trace below. [1] :
> http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 111, in rosdep_main
> exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 232, in _rosdep_main
> return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 255, in _package_args_handler
> lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(options)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 103, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
> lookup = RosdepLookup.create_from_rospkg(sources_loader=sources_loader)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/lookup.py",
> line 298, in create_from_rospkg
> lookup._load_all_views(loader=sources_loader)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/lookup.py",
> line 426, in _load_all_views
> self._load_view_dependencies(resource_name, loader)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/lookup.py",
> line 448, in _load_view_dependencies
> loader.load_view(view_key, db, verbose=self.verbose)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/sources_list.py",
> line 505, in load_view
> rosdep_db.set_view_data(view_name, source.rosdep_data, view_dependencies,
> view_name)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/rosdep2/model.py",
> line 89, in set_view_data
> self._rosdep_db[view_name] = RosdepDatabaseEntry(rosdep_data.copy(),
> view_dependencies, origin)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
> no attribute 'copy'

Maybe I somehow messed up my installation... I already did a reinstallation of Fuerte but the problem persists.

For I'm absolutely new to ROS and Ubuntu I have no clue how to solve or even further analyze the problem. I would very much appreciate any hints what to do at this point?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

It's [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) part of the tutorial I have the mentioned problems with.

When I run

```
$ sudo rosdep init
```

I get

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ sudo rosdep init
[sudo] password for malte:  ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
    /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize
```

When I run

```
$ rosdep update
```

I get the error message

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:

Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:  invalid repo spec
in gbpdistro data: You must update to a newer rosdep version by calling..
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
(make sure to uninstall the pip version on Ubuntu) 
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml]:
Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:  invalid repo spec in gbpdistro data: 
You must update to a newer rosdep version by calling..
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
(make sure to uninstall the pip version on Ubuntu) 
updated cache in /home/malte/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

As suggested by the error message I then ran

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

which worked without errors. Running

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
```

led to the message that the newest version of "python-rosdep" is already installed and that packages "libblas-dev" and "liblapack-dev" were automatically installed.

**EDIT #2:**

For

```
$ which rosdep
```

answered "/usr/local/bin/rosdep" I uninstalled rosdep as suggested below:

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ sudo pip uninstall rosdep [sudo] password for malte:  Uninstalling rosdep:   /usr/bin/rosdep /usr/bin/rosdep-gbp-brew   /usr/bin/rosdep-source   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.3-py2.7.egg Proceed (y/n)? y   Successfully uninstalled rosdep
```

I though I then had to install the newest version:

```
$ sudo pip install -U rosdep
```

but afterwards

```
$ which rosdep
```

again aswered with "/usr/local/bin/rosdep"

Furthermore

```
$ rosdep install turtlesim
```

again led to the error as before:

```
Rosdep experienced an internal error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Is there a way to get rid of the whole installation and start again with a new one? I already tried to deinstall Fuerte by

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-ros
```

and reinstalled it but that did not change anything.

**EDIT #3**

joq, thank you very much for your patience! I'm a total noob...

Unfortunately, I'm still not able to solve the problem. After uninstalling rosdep "which rosdep" answers *nothing* - not even an error message:

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ sudo pip uninstall rosdep
[sudo] password for malte: 
Uninstalling rosdep:
  /usr/local/bin/rosdep
  /usr/local/bin/rosdep-gbp-brew
  /usr/local/bin/rosdep-source
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep-0.9.7.egg-info
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled rosdep
malte@ubuntu:~$ which rosdep
malte@ubuntu:~$
```

And the "rosdep" command is not found.

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ rosdep install turtlesim
rosdep: command not found
```

That's why I thought I have to reinstall it. Running

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
```

I get the message that the newest version of python-rosdep is already installed (the message is in German so I don't post it here).

Any ideas? Thanks again!

**EDIT #4**

Strange things going on...

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -L python-rosdep
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/rosdep
/usr/bin/rosdep-source
/usr/bin/rosdep-gbp-brew
/usr/share
/usr/share/python-support
/usr/share/python-support/python-rosdep.public
/usr/share/pyshared
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep-0.9.7.egg-info
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep-0.9.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep-0.9.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep-0.9.7.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep-0.9.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep-0.9.7.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/installers.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/dependency_graph.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/rospkg_loader.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/model.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/core.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/shell_utils.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/rep3.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/main.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/lookup.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/osx.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/gentoo.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/arch.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/cygwin.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/redhat.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/brewmaker.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/debian.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/opensuse.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/pip.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/freebsd.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/platforms/source.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/catkin_support.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/loader.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/__init__.py
/usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/sources_list.py
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-rosdep
/usr/share/doc/python-rosdep/changelog.Debian.gz
malte@ubuntu:~$ which rosdep
malte@ubuntu:~$ rosdep install turtlesim
rosdep: command not found
malte@ubuntu:~$
```

obviously the list does contain /usr/bin/rosdep. Because "which rosdep" still said nothing I uninstalled and reinstalled python-rosdep again. Now at least "which rosdep" works:

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ which rosdep
/usr/bin/rosdep
```

But "rosdep install turtlesim" still doesn't work, the same error as from begin on:

```
malte@ubuntu:~$ rosdep install turtlesim

ERROR: Rosdep experienced an internal error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 111, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 232, in _rosdep_main
    return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 255, in _package_args_handler
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 103, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    lookup = RosdepLookup.create_from_rospkg(sources_loader=sources_loader)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 299, in create_from_rospkg
    lookup._load_all_views(loader=sources_loader)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 443, in _load_all_views
    self._load_view_dependencies(resource_name, loader)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 465, in _load_view_dependencies
    loader.load_view(view_key, db, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 505, in load_view
    rosdep_db.set_view_data(view_name, source.rosdep_data, view_dependencies, view_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/model.py", line 89, in set_view_data
    self._rosdep_db[view_name] = RosdepDatabaseEntry(rosdep_data.copy(), view_dependencies, origin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Can I do wrong something very stupid???

To be honest, I would prefer to delete/uninstall as much as possible and start again form scratch. It's getting a little bit frustrating...

**EDIT #5**

Meanwhile I rebooted the computer several times - no positive effects on the current problem...

**EDIT #6**

```
find /usr/local -name rosdep2
```

Did not find anything

uninstalling and reinstalling python-rosdep did not solve the problem. When running

```
$ rosdep install turtlesim
```

the same error as before occurred:

```
ERROR: Rosdep experienced an internal error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I don't want to steel your time. If you do not have any other ideas maybe you can just give me some hints how to get rid of **all** components installed during the installation of ROS? Is there any way to start a ROS installation from scratch again? I don't care if that would take an hour - solving this problem in a more elegant way will most likely take much longer (at least for me as a beginner)... It would be a little bit ridiculous to make a new Ubuntu installation just to get back to "tabula rasa", wouldn't it?
Thanks again for your kind help!

**EDIT #7**

I uninstalled ROS rebooted the computer and reinstalled ROS following [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment). Afterwards I again ran through all steps of the tutorial till I reached "[Building a ROS package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages)". When typing

```
$ rosdep install turtlesim
```

the same error as many times before occured:

```
ERROR: Rosdep experienced an internal error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

To sum up: reinstallation did not help at all.

The only little irregularity I experienced during the first steps of the tutorial was that

```
$ roscd
```

did not bring me to ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox (as claimed in the tutorial) but to ~/fuerte_workspace. I don't now why. I moved manually to ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox and continued the tutorial.

Looks like the chance left for me is to get a new Ubuntu installation... Or has someone any other ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42818/tutorial-building-a-ros-package:-%22rosdep-experienced-an-internal-error:-%27nonetype%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27copy%27%22/) by [mta](https://answers.ros.org/users/3125/mta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-09-02

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-05**:
Where does it claim `roscd` goes to `~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox`? This tutorial says (correctly) that it goes to $ROS_WORKSPACE: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem#Special_cases_for_roscd

**Comment by [mta](https://answers.ros.org/users/3125/mta/) on 2012-09-05**:
I meant "1.2 Creating an new ROS package". Maybe I misunderstood but I interpreted "Now go into the ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox directory" and "Alternatively, if you use Fuerte or later release, you can simply do: $ roscd" in the sense that both do the same, i.e. bring me to the sandbox directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is [this the tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) you are running?

Did you run these commands?

```
$ sudo rosdep init
$ rosdep update
```

(Please respond by editing your question.)

UPDATE: you seem to have an old `rosdep` version installed somewhere. What does this show?

```
$ which rosdep
```

If it says something like `/usr/local/bin/rosdep`, then you need to uninstall the `pip` or `easy_install` version you had previously installed. That's simple with `pip`:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall rosdep
```

If you used `easy_install`, you'll have to find and remove all the relevant files by hand.

UPDATE #2: The uninstall was to *remove* the `pip` version in `/usr/local/bin/rosdep`. Then, it will use the correct, up-to-date `/usr/bin/rosdep` automatically installed via apt-get from the `python-rosdep` package. After uninstalling, "`which rosdep`" should show that one.

The `pip` version is *deprecated*, because it leads to exactly this kind of problem.

UPDATE #3: somehow your Debian APT database has gotten screwed up. That is not normal. Does the list of files printed here include `/usr/bin/rosdep`? Does that file exist?

```
$ dpkg -L python-rosdep
```

If not, try uninstalling `python-rosdep` and then reinstalling it again:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python-rosdep
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
```

UPDATE #4: you are not doing anything wrong, this is just a messy problem. I experienced it, too, when the pip version was replaced by the `python-rosdep` package.

I think the which command problem was caused by the shell. It keeps a hash table of commands it has found in the search path. When we deleted /usr/local/bin/rosdeps, it got confused.

I have seen this problem with those pyshared files not getting unpacked into /usr/lib/python2.7 properly, but I can't remember exactly how I resolved it.

It might help to reboot.

UPDATE #5: OK, make sure there is no old version anywhere in /usr/local:

```
$ find /usr/local -name rosdep2
```

If that finds anything at all, delete it. Then, try reinstalling the scripts again:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python-rosdep
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
```

UPDATE #6: I have no expectation that uninstalling everything would help. This is not Windows.

But, if you want to try that, this should remove all of ROS (note the single-quote characters):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python-rosdep 'ros-fuerte-*'
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-04**:
one of my friends also got a similar error and we somehow managed to solve it. I think sometimes improper dependency lists for some stacks also cause this issue. I do not remember exactly how the error went away but I'll post if I remember. Am sure I dint do so many things mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

try this to resolve the problem:

```
sudo pip uninstall rosdep
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-rosdep
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
bash
roscd
sudo rosdep init
sudo rosdep update
```

Simon

---

Originally posted by [Simon Lynen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1211/simon-lynen/) with karma: 116 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a lot here so I don't know whether you've got your answer yet or not, but I don't think anyone has said these steps explicitly. The installation requires you to uninstall the pip version if you're running Ubuntu (and trying to install ros-groovy). So follow the installation guide normally up to this step

```
$ rosdep update
```

Then if you get the error again after reinstalling Ubuntu (which you said you're doing in your final edit, however that should not affect anything), call:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall rosdep
```

to remove the pip version, then try again with

```
$ sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
$ sudo rosdep init
$ rosdep update
```

Hope that works

---

Originally posted by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) with karma: 215 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2